# What is the suitable temperature for a motor to work without failing?

Tags: temperature, electrical-engineering

How much body temperature can a motor withstand along with the ambient temperature to work without failing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about biophysics.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the datasheet says it can sustain, of course.